# usage of conj in core.typed

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

The following code snippet in `core.typed`

```
(defn conj-num [coll x]
  (conj coll (byte x)))

(t/cf (t/ann conj-num (t/IFn [(t/ASeq t/Any) t/Any -> (t/ASeq t/Num)])))

(t/cf (reduce conj-num [] (range 10)))
```

fails with the message

```
Type Error...
Polymorphic function reduce could not be applied to arguments: 
Polymorphic Variables:  a   c

Domains:    [a c -> (t/U a (Reduced a))] a (t/Option (Seqable c))

Arguments:  [(t/ASeq t/Any) t/Any -> (t/ASeq t/Num)] (t/HVec []) (t/ASeq t/AnyInteger)

Ranges:     a


in: (reduce conj-num [] (range 10))


ExceptionInfo Type Checker: Found 1 error  clojure.core/ex-info (core.clj:4403)
```

The reducing fn accepts an `ASeq of Any` and another argument of type `Any` and returns a sequence of numbers. I have expected that the result of the type checker was `(t/ASeq t/Num)` rather than an error. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thank you.

*Edit*

Thanks for the responses. I was able to figure out the problem now. It wasn't clear how to interpret the error message given by `core.typed`, but now it really makes sense.

I read the error message above now as follows

```
Polymorphic Variables:
    a
    c
```

-> this are the variables of the `reduce` function. you can determine it's signature (or type) with `(t/cf reduce)`. It will show you 3 arities, but the following message specifies which arity was chosen and why it didn't match.

```
Domains:
    [a c -> (t/U a (Reduced a))] a (t/Option (Seqable c))
```

`Core.typed` also gives us ranges. I read them as *the variables that couldn't be matched*.

```
Ranges:
    a
```

So we have to focus on `a`. `Core.typed` seems happy about `b`.

The following message is about the actual type being matched (the type of our arguments are matched against the type defined by the `reduce` fn).

```
Arguments:
    [(t/HVec [t/Num]) t/Any -> (t/HVec [t/Num])] (t/HVec []) (t/ASeq t/Num)
```

We match it by hand

```
[(t/HVec [t/Num ]) t/Any -> (t/HVec [t/Num])] (t/HVec []) (t/ASeq t/Num)
  --------------  -----    ----------------   --------   ------------
    a               b      (t/U a (Reduced a)    a       (t/Option ...)
```

The following is now evident

- `a` must be of type `(t/HVec [t/Num])` because of the first occurence AND also `(t/HVec [])` because of the second occurence of `a`. Since it can't be both of them, core.typed correctly fails.
- the type `(t/U a (Reduced a))` matches any `a` or a reduced `a`. I don't understand what `Reduced a` means (maybe it has to do with transducers?), but `t/U` just means it can match either or. So in our case it's just `a` itself.

What is missing in this example is to make sure that the type a has to match on both side, for instance:

```
;; a is still a vector
(def a [])

;; we give the type (t/HVec [t/Num]) to a. This makes it *more* compatible with our conj-num fn.

(t/cf (t/ann a (t/HVec [t/Num])))

;; core.typed is happy now ;)
(t/cf (reduce conj-num a (range 10)))
```

It's ofc not satisfying to hack about `a`. The problem is that `conj-num` is just not defined in a helpful way. It is very rigid. It basically doesn't allow the accumulator to be just a vector. Here's the final type:

```
(t/cf (t/ann conj-num
            (t/IFn [(t/U (t/HVec [])
                         (t/HVec [t/Num])) t/Num -> (t/HVec [t/Num])])))

;; great. we can now use [] as input.
(t/cf (reduce conj-num [] (range 10)))
```

This signature now works because the first argument `a` can now be either an empty vector `(t/HVec [])` or a vector of nums `(t/HVec [t/Num])` which is exactly what conj-num returns. So all good now. It just seems that learning `core.typed` really is about learning how to read these error message. But it seems less hard now. Thanks for your answer, it helped me analyze the message and find a fix for it.

Comment: [(t/U (t/HVec [])
                         (t/HVec [t/Num])) t/Num -> (t/HVec [t/Num])]

t/HVec []) is unnecessary.

 (t/HVec [t/Num]) typechecks [] (empty vec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very probably because the type checking engine cannot match the type variable a.

Look:

Domains:    [a c -> (t/U a (Reduced a))] a (t/Option (Seqable c))

Arguments:  [(t/ASeq t/Any) t/Any -> (t/ASeq t/Num)] (t/HVec []) (t/ASeq t/AnyInteger)

Ranges:     a

"c" is t/Any, that's done. Now for "a", on the left side of -> "a" is (t/Aseq t/Any) and on the right side (t/U a (Reduced a)) is (t/ASeq t/Num). It doesn't match. I would advise to change conj-num type to:

[(t/ASeq t/Num) t/Any -> (t/ASeq t/Num)]

Comment: thanks for the explanation. it helped me find a solution for it. see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering of your commands means that your function `conj-num` is not being checked.

I recommend instead checking this in a file.

```
(ns typed.test
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :as t]))

(t/ann conj-num (t/IFn [(t/ASeq t/Any) t/Any -> (t/ASeq t/Num)]))
(defn conj-num [coll x]
  (conj coll (byte x)))

(reduce conj-num [] (range 10))
```

The definition of `conj-num` does not correspond to the annotation, so should throw a type error.

Comment: yeah, I am testing core.typed in the repl atm. And you're right about the annotation problem. It just wasn't clear to me. I thought it would automagically resolve the problem for me. I learned that you have to be quite precise with your annotations otherwise you get in trouble. But it seems to be less hard than I originally expected. Thanks for this nice clojure lib.

Comment: I am not sure if I read the error message from core.typed correctly. I have made an edit to my question and describe how I interpret it. Can you tell me my interpretation is correct?